# Binding a Button to a GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, button

This a pretty simple question, I'm just not sure how to do it exactly. I would like to bind a Button or perhaps ImageButton to a GridView in ASP.NET/C#. Currently, the GridView has two columns and is bound to a DataTable with two columns. I want to add a third column to the GridView, which will include the Button.

I know GridView has ButtonField, but I'm not too sure how to go about using it to do what I want. I want to dynamically generate these Buttons and add them to the GridView.

Here is how my GridView looks right now:

```
<asp:GridView 
    ID="GridView1"
    Runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:HyperLinkField 
            HeaderText="Display Name"
            DataNavigateUrlFields="DISPNAME"
            DataNavigateUrlFormatString="ViewItem.aspx"
            DataTextField="DISPNAME">
            <ItemStyle Width="70%" />
        </asp:HyperLinkField>
        <asp:BoundField
            DataField="TypeDisp"
            HeaderText="Type">
            <ItemStyle Width="20%" />
        </asp:BoundField>
    </Columns>
 </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a template field like the following,

```
<TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="image url" CommandName="SomeCommand" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>'/>
    </ItemTemplate>
</TemplateField>
```

Then you can handle the RowCommand event of the GridView and check the e.CommandName to see what command to be executed and you can get the e.CommandArgument as well which could be the row Id like I used in the code above.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like a viable solution. I'll try it out Monday and report back.

Answer (score 1):

If we are talking a button that's always present, you can use ButtonField, or even use a TemplateField and provide the template with the button, and bind the data to the button (sounds like you may want to bind data to the attributes of the button?)

If you are looking to dynamically generate buttons in the UI, tap into the RowCreated event and add the button the GridView.  You'd have to do this on every page load; the GridView won't remember a button created programmatically.

HTH.